# Constructing lax limits from lax limits

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, enriched-category-theory

Let $K$ be a 2-category. It's well-known that if $K$ has all [PIE limits](https://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/PIE-limit), then $K$ also has all lax limits. But I don't know a general "limit-decomposition" result which works "internally" to the lax world.

**Question 1:** Let $K$ be a 2-category. Suppose that $K$ has finite products, split idempotents, and lax limits of 1-morphisms. Then does $K$ have all lax limits weighted by essentially finite 2-categorical weights?

Here, a *2-categorical weight* is a 2-functor $W : I \to Cat$, and $W$ is *essentially finite* if it is a compact object of that $Cat$-enriched functor category (equivalently, if $W$ is in the closure of the corepresentable weights under initial objects, pushouts, split idempotents, and copowering with the arrow category $[1]$). The *lax limit* weighted by $W$ of a functor $F : I \to K$ is an object $[ W, F]^\ell \in K$ which represents (in the $Cat$-enriched sense) the 2-functor $k \mapsto 2Nat_{i \in I}(W(i), Hom_{[ I, K ]^\ell} (k,Fi))$, where $[-,-]^\ell$ is the left internal hom on $2Cat$ associated to the Gray tensor product. A *lax limit of a 1-morphism* is the case where $I = [1]$ is the arrow category and $W$ is the terminal weight.

**Question 2:** Let $K$ be a 2-category with small products, split idempotents, and lax limits of 1-morphisms. Then does $K$ have all lax limits with arbitrary 2-categorical weights?

**Notes:**

- Lax pullbacks can be constructed from finite products and limits of lax morphisms, if I'm not mistaken.
- More generally, I think I have a proof that under the conditions of Question 1, $K$ has all lax limits indexed by any finite poset with the terminal weight. I'm not sure how close this is to a complete solution.